# MySQL allowing NULL in field defined as NO NULLS

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table 'wp_mgf_visits' with the field 'photo' defined as 'NO NULL'.  Trying to insert a record with NULL in this field fails (as it should).  However, the following statement executes and removes the value in the record concerned:

```
    UPDATE `wp_mgf_visits` SET `photo` = NULL WHERE photo = 'myslug4'
```

The statement was executed in phpMyAdmin. Should this be happening;  does the 'NO NULL' interdiction only apply to insertions?

In answer to the questions, the field is defined as NO NULL and with no default:

[image: Extract from table definition]

Comment: show us the create table and see if photo has a default value

Comment: @nbk Thanks for the comment; I 've added a screenshot of the relevant part of the table definition.  As you will see: no nulls allowed and no default value.

Comment: please don't post umages see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Comment: Understand about the images but I could not think of any other way to provide the information: there is no CREATE TABLE code, for example. I apologise for not following all the conventions but I do not post here very often.  In the meantime, does anyone have any answers to my basic question?

Comment: there no chance that this will go through, check if you have a update trigger and also the result of the query https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=97a1dc98404c0fb68487ea32dab73c93

Comment: Thanks for the dbfiddle.  There is something strange going on.  I took your UPDATE statement and executed it on my table in phpMyAdmin.  I got a warning saying that the column could not be NULL but looking at the table afterwards, the column was null.  I have made a Loom recording here: https://www.loom.com/share/196c583e5da24e578b6d7b43ddc0c842

Comment: I should also explain that this is not really my problem. It happened in a WordPress plugin (a well-known premium one with tens of thousands of users, not some amateur effort).  I discussed it with the developers and they are as puzzled as I am.  I then did the test in phpMyAdmin to see if the problem was more general than the plugin and, from the results, it looks like it is. That's the reason for my question here.

Comment: I am beginning to think that this might be a database version problem.  In the fiddle, you used MySQL 8.0.  Most previous versions also reject the statement but version 5.5 accepts it. I checked what database my hoster is using and it's MariaDB 10.3.29. In the fiddle, the latest versions of MariaDB also reject the statement.  Unfortunately, MariaDB 10.3 in the fiddle won't execute ('Run failed') so I can't test it.

Comment: there is an update to 10.3.30, see if this fixes your problem.

Comment: After some more digging, this problem is down to a confusion (mine!) between NULL and empty string (which is what the phpMyAdmin test is setting - not NULL). That said, it seems to me that, if the statement fails (as it should as NULL is not allowed), then the original value should be preserved and not replaced by an empty string.

Comment: make an update and insert trigger

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it is phpMyAdmin which seems not to be behaving properly.

Answer (score 1):

Good day.. Check to see if the column is defined as 'NOT NULL' or 'NULL' or maybe it has a default value so you can verify if you can update it to 'NULL' or simply ''.

Comment: Thanks for replying. As I wrote in the original post, the column is defined as 'nulls not allowed' and I'll now say that it does not have a default value.  I have added a screenshot to my original post to show the relevant part of the table definition.  Any light you can shed on this problem will be much appreciated.

Comment: Good day, as I see from the images and the query provided. It is defined as 'NO NULL' meaning it cannot be 'NULL' and so it cannot be updated to 'NULL' based on my understanding.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I know that it should not happen - but it does! See the link to the video in my comment to nbk above.